# Проблема с std::string

Tags: c++, stl

Не могу понять, как сложить строки?

```
   std::string to_string( const char* format, ... ) {
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, format );
        const std::size_t len = _vscprintf( format, args ) + 1;
        std::string str( len, '\0' );
        vsprintf_s( &str[0], len, format, args );
        str.resize( len );
        return ( str );
    }

    int main() {

        std::string num( "num = " );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            //num += to_string( "%d", i ).c_str(); так оно работает
            num += to_string( "%d", i ); // num = 0 и все
        }

        printf_s( "%s\n", num.c_str() );
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Когда к std::string прилепят format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас [почти] все работает прекрасно, но именно так как вы и написали. В конце вашей функции `to_string` вы делаете

```
str.resize( len );
```

где `len` включает и нулевой терминатор тоже. То есть из вашей функции вы возвращаете строки

```
"0\0"
"1\0"
"2\0"
"3\0"
...
```

и т.д. А потом вы эти строки конкатенируете в одну и получаете

```
0 \0 1 \0 2 \0 3 \0 ...
```

Все работает, как и должно работать. Строки `std::string` не являются нуль-терминированными и в их составе символ `'\0'` является обыкновенным символом.

Однако при попытке печати такой последовательности через `printf`, разумеется, печать идет только до первого `'\0'`. Напечатайте ваш результат через

```
std::cout << num << std::endl;
```

и вы увидите, что все элементарные строки в составе вашей строки присутствуют. То есть все у вас прекрасно соединяется, только вы зачем-то напихали внутрь вашей строки ненужных нулей.

Память для каждого нуля внутри вашей функции изначально выделять нужно (ибо вы пользуетесь `vsprintf_s`), но перед возвращением результирующего значения этот нуль из строки надо убрать, т.е. в вашем случае сделать

```
str.resize( len - 1 );
```

Также не забывайте делать `va_end` и перезапускать `va_list` (даже если майкрософтовские примеры иногда "забывают" это делать).

(Максимально сохраняя ваш подход)

```
std::string to_string( const char* format, ... ) {
    va_list args;

    va_start( args, format );
    std::size_t len = _vscprintf( format, args );
    va_end( args );

    std::string str( len + 1, '\0' );

    va_start( args, format );
    vsprintf_s( &str[0], len + 1, format, args );
    va_end( args );

    str.resize( len );
    return str;
}
```

---

Функциональность, которую вы пытаетесь реализовать (раз уж вы хотите сделать это именно так), уже давно можно реализовать стандартными средствами через `vsnprintf`, без привлечения нестандартных майкрософтовских средств

```
std::string to_string( const char* format, ... ) {
    va_list args;

    va_start( args, format );
    std::size_t len = std::vsnprintf( nullptr, 0, format, args );
    va_end( args );

    std::string str( len + 1, '\0' );

    va_start( args, format );
    std::vsnprintf( &str[0], len + 1, format, args );
    va_end( args );

    str.resize( len );
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Развернуто и ясно! Ток про va_ не понял.

Comment: @ur4ik: После того, как вы передали `args` в `vsnprintf` (и `vsnprintf` как-то внутри себя его использовал) это значение `args` считается "протухшим" и использовать его еще раз уже нельзя. Например, его нельзя второй раз передавать  в `vsnprintf`. Его только можно (и нужно) "уничтожить" через `va_end`.  Чтобы два раза пройтись по одному и тому же списку аргументов надо либо снова начисто переиницализировать `args` через `va_start` (как у меня выше), либо "запомнить" исходное, еще не "протухшее" значение `args` через `va_copy` (как в коде у Harry) и для второго прохода использовать эту копию.

Answer (score 2):

Откровенно говоря - это какое-то извращение, в С++ так работать...
Но если очень уж хочется, то я бы делал примерно так:

```
string to_string( const char* format, ... )
{
    va_list args, copy;
    va_start(args, format);
    va_copy(copy,args);
    char * buf = new char[vsnprintf(0,0,format,args)+1];
    vsnprintf(buf, len+1, format, copy );
    va_end(args);
    va_end(copy);
    string str(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    cout << str << endl;
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    string num( "num = " );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        num += to_string( "%d", i ); // num = 0 и все
    }

    cout << num << endl;
}
```

А вообще - ну лучше уж стандартной [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) обойтись. Или, для сложного форматирования - [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). А так получается - какое-то натягивание пиджака на осьминога. Уж лучше тогда средствами C изначально пользоваться, не привлекая никакие `string`.

Comment: Да согласен, жесткий бед :D Просто есть необходимость часто записывать форматированные данные в стринг.

Answer (score -2):

Так работает*

```
template<typename ... Args>
__inline std::string to_string( const char* format, Args ... args ) {
    int len = _scprintf( format, args ... );
    std::string str( len + 1, '\0' );
    sprintf_s( &str[0], len + 1, format, args ... );
    str.resize( len );
    return ( str );
}
```

Comment: Кто поставил минусы — вы бы откомментировали, что в ответе не так.